# Is there a legal way for me to embed the Calibri font into a website for non Windows Vista/7 visitors?

Tags: embed, font-face

I would like to use Calibri for my website.

I would like to use the Calibri font for my website even when the visitor does not have the font installed (ie. non Windows Vista/7 visitors).

Does Microsoft allow embedding of the Calibri font into a Web Site?

If so, what technology do they allow this? EOT?

Thanks.

Comment: www.cssfontstack.com suggests a usage like this: `font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;`

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about legal font usage.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You might want to check this discussion at http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=63055

I would just put Calibri in the CSS followed by the fonts that match Calibri the closest. For example:

```
font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Your website will then take the best available font.

Depending on the type of visitors your website is meant for most visitors should have Windows Vista or Windows 7 and thus have the Calibri font available for viewing your website.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.

The problem with listing Calibri first is that it is smaller than Verdana or Arial. Visitors without Calibri see very large (ugly) text.

I am going to try serving the free Droid font to those who do not have Calibri. I saw that font from the link you provided so thank you for the tip.

Comment: Try it this way (http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_font-size_px), it says that IE isn't supported but that might refer to IE 6 and earlier versions. Works fine in IE 7 and later as far as I can see.

Comment: I'd just use Calibri with a different fallback font. Verdana is notoriously chunky, far too big for its point size, which makes it a bad choice to mix with others in a fallback chain.

Answer (score 48):

Somehow, **Google** has Calibri and Cambria in their directory. You might be able to use it through their link:

**Calibri** → https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calibri:400,700,400italic,700italic

**Cambria** → https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cambria:400,700,400italic,700italic

Comment: I get 403 forbidden :( Has the link be Changed?

Comment: For whatever reason, just http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calibri:400,700,400italic,700italic works, even though the catalog link sends people to fonts.com

Comment: @Christian Gollhardt Try this: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calibri:400,700,400italic,700italic and http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cambria:400,700,400italic,700italic

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer?! It's perfect, and significantly more reliable/cross platform than the other answer :-/

Comment: To anyone who is experiencing a 403 when viewing the above links, try the same url with https instead of http and they should work.

Comment: Ok.. found the cause of 403. link should be https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calibri:400,700,400i,700i

Comment: So obviously this sould be safe, but can somebody please explain why this is? (Because one does not host it by itself?)

Comment: @hobailey: Adding a font through a non-published link without license information? Sounds like a recipe for getting sued to me...

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this works displaying in the browser but it doesn't when I use a tool that exports svgs to images

Answer (score 9):

Calibri is available as a web font from several provider:

http://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/calibri?QueryFontType=Web#buying-options

Comment: That's not free, it costs at least 49€

Comment: That's the legal way OP is looking for